# Swift 5. 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(...) instead

Tags: swift

I have the method which has to print the username when the user connected but the error **withUnsafeBytes is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R instead** pops up.

method:

```
    func joinChat(username: String) {
      let data = "iam:\(username)".data(using: .ascii)!
      self.username = username
      _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength:    data.count) } //deprecated
    }
```

Somebody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find some solutions on how to use new `Data.withUnsafeBytes`, but if you are using it just for calling `OutputStream.write`, you have another option:

```
func joinChat(username: String) {
    let str = "iam:\(username)"
    self.username = username
    outputStream.write(str, maxLength: str.utf8.count)
}
```

This code does not have a feature that crashes your app when `username` contains non-ascii characters, but other than that, it would work.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like `withUnsafeBytes` relies on `assumingMemoryBound(to:)` on Swift 5, there are some threads regarding it, e.g: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811

To silence that error, you could:

```swift
func joinChat(username: String) {
    let data = "iam:\(username)".data(using: .ascii)!
    self.username = username
    _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
        let buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = dataBytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        OutputStream(toMemory: ()).write(buffer, maxLength: dataBytes.count)
    }
}
```

But it seems unsafe and confusing. It would be better to go with @OOper solution I think.

Comment: Warning is stopping with this as stream!